# ¿Cómo mostrar los valores de un arreglo que recibo de un json en Angular?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

Recibo el siguiente json:

```
{
    "id": "7654321212",
    "lugar": "1",
    "procedencia": "E",
    "estado": "3",
    "fecha": "20210421",
    "hora": "010821",
    "series": [
        {
            "pin": "000000",
            "status": "2"
        },
        {
            "pin": "00300",
            "status": "1"
        }}
```

En Angular lo recibo de la siguiente forma, mi model:

```
export class Muestras {

    id: string;
    lugar: string;
    procedencia: string;
    estado: string;
    fecha: string;
    hora: string;
    series: string;
}
```

En el onInit:

```
muestras: Muestras[];

this.muestra.getMuestras().subscribe(e => {
    this.embarques = e;
```

Si se imprimen los valores como el id, pero no puedo extraer el valor del arreglo series, se puede solo desde el html o tiene que ser desde typescript.

Comment: deberías poder usar el objeto desde cualquier parte, HTML o Typescript, quizás lo que te está pasando es que estas usando el objeto antes de que te lleguen los valores ya que el método `getMuestras` retorna un observable que puede demorar un poco en llegar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las series que recibes de tu json es un array, para solucionar el problema debes definirlo de esa forma.

```
//ARREGLO SERIES
export class Series {
  pin: string;
  status: string;
}

//OBJETO MUESTRAS
export class Muestras {
  id: string;
  lugar: string;
  procedencia: string;
  estado: string;
  fecha: string;
  hora: string;
  series: Series[]; //Lo que recibes aquí vendría a ser un array y no un string
}
```

Al recibir tu información en el OnInit le asignas los datos de tu json a tu modelo para modo prueba esta incluido jsonInfo, ahí recibirías desde tu api o servicio.

```
muestras: Muestras;

  //INFORMACIÓN DE TU JSON
  jsonInfo: any = {
    id: "7654321212",
    lugar: "1",
    procedencia: "E",
    estado: "3",
    fecha: "20210421",
    hora: "010821",
    series: [
      {
        pin: "000000",
        status: "2"
      },
      {
        pin: "00300",
        status: "1"
      }
    ]
  };

  ngOnInit() {
    //Agregas el json a tu model
    this.muestras = this.jsonInfo;

    //Imprimer tu model
    console.log(this.muestras);
  }
```

Te dejo el ejemplo en stackblitz [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xyl8pu)